# Convergence of the ratio of two sequences

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(a_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(b_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ two real valued sequences such that $a_j \nearrow +\infty$ and $b_j \nearrow +\infty$. 
Is it possible to extract  subsequences $(a_{j_i})_i$ and  $(b_{j_i})_i$ such that $(\frac{a_{j_i}}{b_{j_i}})_i$ converges to  a positive finite number?

Any help will be very apreciated! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. Suppose that $a_j=j^2$ and that $b_j=j$. Then $\frac{a_j}{b_j}=j$ for each $j\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry, but I realized that I haven't been very clear in my question. I want to allow to take two possibly different subsequences. For instance, your example is not a counterexample, because I can take a subsequence of $b_j$ such that it is equal to the sequence $a_j$ and then I take the ratio.

Comment: Let me edit my question to make it more precise!

Comment: Editing a question with correct answers an a way that changes the question is not a correct behaviour. If you have another question, you should post it as such.

Comment: You are totally right! Ok, I can re-edit the question and leave it in the original form (even if that wasn't the question I had in mind) and I will accept your answer. Then I'll make another post with the question I actually wanted to ask.

Comment: I've created a new post here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3318148/making-the-ratio-of-two-sequences-converge

Answer (score 1):

No. If $a_j >jb_j$ then $\frac {a_{j(i)}} {b_{j(i)}} >j(i)$ and $j(i)\to \infty$ as $ i \to \infty$ whatever be the subsequence $(j(i))$.