# Making the ratio of two sequences converge

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(a_j)_j$ and $(b_k)_k$ be two real valued sequences such that $a_j \nearrow +\infty$ and $b_k \nearrow +\infty$.

Is it possible to extract (independently) two susequences $(a_{j_i})_i$ and $(b_{k_i})_i$ such that the ratio $(\frac{a_{j_i}}{b_{k_i}})_i$ converges to a finite number?

**EDITED** Is it possible to make the limit strictly positive?

This question looks very similar to this other one: [Convergence of the ratio of two sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3318130/convergence-of-the-ratio-of-two-sequences/3318134#3318134) 
but here we allow the two subsequences to be extract independently. For instance the example given in the accepted answer doesn't is not a counter example here.

Comment: You only need to find subsequences such that the quotient is bounded. Taking another subsequence will then yield a convergent subsequence by Bolzano-Weierstrass.

Comment: @Klaus Exactly! I would like to prove that there exists subsequences such that for some $l, L >0 $ I have $l b_{k_i} \le a_{j_i} \le L b_{k_i}$. But is it true?

Answer (score 2):

The second part about making the limit strictly positive has been added later. This is an answer to the original question.

Without loss of generality we assume that $a_n, b_n >0$ for all $n$. For each $i$ choose $k(i)$ such that $a_i < b_{k(i)}$. Then $\frac {a_i} {b_{k(i)}}$ is bounded so it has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Thanks a lot! With your construction the limit can be $0$. Is it possible to make the limit not be equal to $0$?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more? I can't see how to make it work..

Comment: Once again,I think you should ask a new question if you want the limit to be non-zero.